# Testcafe filter function

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a filter function for Selector  as following which accepts two parameters 
 `{ subject: subject,  from: from }` as a dependencies object.

But after running this function, I am getting an error

> ReferenceError: subject is not defined

```
async function getMessage(subject, from) {
  return await Selector('[data-test=messageListItem]').filter(( message ) => {
    return message.querySelector('[data-test=subject]').textContent.includes(subject) &&
      message.querySelector('[data-test=email]').textContent.includes(from);
  }, { dependencies: { subject: subject,  from: from } });
}
```

Can TestCafe team please help me with this?

Comment: Thanks    Nipun Tharuksha    for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the case of the `.filter` method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#filter) you need to rewrite your dependencies parameter (`{ dependencies: { subject: subject,  from: from } }`) as follows:

```
{ subject: subject,  from: from }
```

I have prepared a sample test to illustrate it:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `google.com`;

test('New Test', async t => {
    await t
        .click(Selector('#tsf').find('[name="q"]'))
        .typeText(Selector('#tsf').find('[name="q"]'), 'testcafe')
        .pressKey('enter');

    await t.expect(Selector('.LC20lb').count).eql(10);


    function fn (title) {
        return Selector('.LC20lb').filter((node, idx) => {
            return node.textContent.includes(title);
        }, { title }); // dependencies parameter
    }

    await t.expect(fn('TestCafe').count).gt(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering it worked !!  But Would like to know if for 'Selector' function also this is the way to pass dependencies ? As the documentation says following:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe'; 

const persistentId = { key: 'value' };

const element = Selector(() => {
    return getElementByCustomId(persistentId);
}, {
    dependencies: { persistentId }
});
```

Comment: As the documentation says, you should use the syntax like `{ dependencies: { persistentId } }` for the `Selector` constructor. The difference is that the `Selector` can get other options too, not just dependencies (e.g. `{ dependencies: { persistentId }, timeout: 3000 }`), while the `filter` gets dependencies only.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vladimir A.
I had the same issue, and looks like I shouldn't have skipped the "Optional" parameter for the filtering function in TestCafe.

You can refer to [Selector.filter Method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402753/reference/test-api/selector/filter#header)
-> Go to **filter(filterFn, dependencies)**
and read the description for the optional parameter **dependencies (optional)**:

> Functions, variables, or objects passed to the filterFn function.